# Error java: variable ya definida en el metodo main String al intentar usar un for-loop

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Estoy intentando crear un código simple en Java, siendo este un listado de objetos con valores que se recogen en un array, y luego usar *for* para sacar un tipo de dato en especifico. Al llegar a instanciar *for* NetBeans me da como error de que ya está definida. Este sería el código. El error en especifico es "variable arrayCasas is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])"

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        House house1 = new House();
        house1.address = "Calle Altamirano 17";
        house1.rooms = 5;
        house1.zipCode= "28008";
        house1.squareM = 120;
                
        House house2 = new House();
        house2.address = "Calle San Juan 24";
        house2.rooms = 3;
        house2.zipCode = "28135";
        house2.squareM = 85;
                
        House house3 = new House();
        house3.address = "Calle Vicente Vallés 8";
        house3.rooms = 1;
        house3.zipCode = "28040";
        house3.squareM = 45;
        
        
        House arrayCasas[] = {house1, house2, house3};
        
       for (House arrayCasas : arrayCasas){
           System.out.println("Direcciones: " + arrayCasas.address);
       }
            
    }
}
```

Aparte tengo creada la clase House en la que marco los valores que quiero que tengan los objetos.

He intentado cambiarle el nombre al array y separar la declaración, pero me sigue dando error. También he leído el caso de otras personas que postearon aquí pero no me queda clara la solución.

Comment: tu ciclo for se puede interpretar como que estas intenando iterar un objeto tipo House llamado ```arrayCasas``` en el array llamado ```arrayCasas``` por eso el error usa otro nombre ```for (House casas : arrayCasas)```

Answer (score 2):

El error:

> "variable arrayCasas is already defined in method
> main(java.lang.String[])"

indica que la variable `arrayCasas` , fue previamente definida, por lo tanto, no puedes volver a definirla

Simplemente usa otra variable para obtener cada elemento del arrayCasas en la iteración, puedes usar por ejemplo `casa` para obtener cada objeto del array y de esta forma obtener las propiedades de este objeto sin problema:

```
  //for (House arrayCasas : arrayCasas){
    for (House casa : arrayCasas){
        System.out.println("Direcciones: " + casa.address);
    }
```